# How to return from the outer function from the callback of setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the best way to achieve this?

```
const func = (newPermissions) => {
  this.setState({
    permissions: { ...newPermissions }
  },
  () => {
    if (this.state.permissions.read) {
      // If we get here then func should return the result of an api call
      // Currently the return just returns from callback of setState and func returns nothing
      return api.getInfo().then((response) => {
        return response;
      });
    }
  });
}
```

I tried directly returning from the callback but it just returns from the callback of setState and func returns nothing.

### Update: Potential Solution

Would this be a potential solution?

```
const func = (newPermissions) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.setState({
      permissions: { ...newPermissions }
    },
    () => {
      if (this.state.permissions.read) {
        resolve(api.getInfo().then((response) => {
          return response;
        }));
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No other way than using a promise

```
const func = (newPermissions) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.setState({
      permissions: { ...newPermissions }
    },
    () => {
      if (this.state.permissions.read) {
        return api.getInfo().then((response) => {
          resolve(response);
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Or another callback

```
const func = (newPermissions, callback) => {
  this.setState({
    permissions: { ...newPermissions }
  },
  () => {
    if (this.state.permissions.read) {
      return api.getInfo().then((response) => {
        callback(response);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: There are other ways. Or other syntaxes I should say

Comment: @Normal what other syntaxes do you mean?

Comment: Just asking out of curosity, will  [flushAsync](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react-dom/flushSync#flushing-updates-for-third-party-integrations) help in such cases, provided we are working with functional components

Comment: @Azzy I'm not sure, but it sounds like it should work here

Comment: @Konrad would the updated potential solution above also work